# Error message from form validation using a model method for custom rule

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need to display an error message for a custom validation rule, but I can't get to do it.

This is the validation rule:

```
    $config = array(
             ....,
            array(
                    'field' => 'general_sales_subaccount',
                    'label' => 'General Sales Subaccount',
                    'rules' => array(
                            'required',
                            'numeric',
                            array(
                                    $this->subaccounts_model,
                                    'is_valid'
                            )
                    ),
            )
    );

    $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
```

And now this is the referenced model method:

```
    public function is_valid($subaccount)
    {
        $subaccount_num_digits = $this->preferences->get('subaccount_num_digits');

        if (strlen($subaccount) != $subaccount_num_digits ) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('is_valid', "The number of digits in %s doesn't match the length set to " . $subaccount_num_digits);
            return false;
        }       

        return true;
    }
```

The rule seems to work, but it displays this error message:

**Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name (Anonymous function).**

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way of doing that with a model method as a rule.

Comment: That's too bad. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get an error message because you don't setup functions name. You may change your rule function like below:

```
$config = array(
         ....,
        array(
                'field' => 'general_sales_subaccount',
                'label' => 'General Sales Subaccount',
                'rules' => array(
                        'required',
                        'numeric',
                        array( //you may get all in another array
                          'is_valid', // and tell codeigniter your functions name
                          array(
                                $this->subaccounts_model,
                                'is_valid'
                        )
                    )
                ),
        )
);

$this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
```